# Load same page with different URLs?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I want to create a single page such as this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/special/index.html

But anything in the /special/ folder should be able to load the index.html page.  For example, if you go to

http://www.mywebsite.com/special/another-page.html

It should still load the index page but not change the URL in the browser or to search engines.  Basically, you should be able to go to any page in the /special/ folder, keep the URL the same as you enter, but always load the index.html page.  Any ideas?

A 404 or 301 redirect wouldn't work because that changes the URL in the browser and to search engines...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would look something about configuring it at Apache server. Some way of mapping urls.

Comment: Why would you want to allow that? If Google starts indexing the same page at a bunch of URLs, it's going to start kicking your site down in the results for "cheating."

Comment: @rogelware - duplicate content at different urls. A lot of shady sites have tried to do that to stuff keywords and get Google to index it, when it's really the same page twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (untested) something like this would work in an .htaccess file in the special directory if you have the ability to use rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html
```

You would have to symlink index.html in the special directory to the real index.html.

The `^.*$` just means (beginning of line)(any amount of anything)(end of line) - basically a wildcard; there might be a better way of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

A 404 redirect would not help, but a custom 404 handler would:

error404.php:

```
<?php
include('path/to/special/index.html');
?>
```

Assuming .html is a static or PHP page. If it is something else, youse the equivalent construct of that environment.

Answer (score 1):

Using apache mapping it should be possible. I don't how to exactly do that but this doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/urlmapping.html probably has the answer.

It is possible to use patterns to map URL to filesystem locations.